# Access Salesforce CRM Content in Communities & public VF pages

Tags: content, contentversion, public-group, libraries

- We have a requirement to put a custom download link on VF page for
  few Salesforce CRM Content.
- We would like to share few Salesforce content with **"Community
  User"** and few Salesforce Content with guest users also who can
  download files without logging in to communities.
- It should be possible to provide access of content to **"Community
  User"** by adding Community user to Library.
- But I am not sure, how can we make a content public which can be
  downloaded without any authentication.

Please suggest, if someone has done Similar in Salesforce.

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Shukla

Comment: Which CRM contents you want to share with guest user and community user ?
In which form you want to share them to be able to make those contents ready to download ? @Ashsih

Comment: Hi @Abbas,  I want  to share this content in form of a downloadable link on a Visualforce page. So, I would like to generate a URL for  every public content, which can be accisible via a public URL.

Comment: All use cases can be achieved except guest user one. How are you going to distinguish few guest users. Do we list guest users somewhere in sf org ?

Comment: Hi Ankuli,  as we can make some pages as public in community website by adding that pages into site 's settings.  By this way guest users(any public user) can view that page.   This setting can be found in "public access settings" in "Site Settings" page. Such users uses "Guest User License" for viewing public pages. So, we can differentiate such users in VF page by  their "Guest User License".